# Use Clip Function to with Gradient Effect with JavaScript on Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to use the `clip()` function in canvas to create this effect, as pictured: there is a background image, and when your mouse hover on it, part of the image is shown. I got it to work as a circle, but I want this gradient effect you see the picture. How do I achieve that?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/stylesheet/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/stylesheet/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="1200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
      var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

      can.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
          var mouse = getMouse(e, can);
          redraw(mouse);
      }, false);

      function redraw(mouse) {
          console.log('a');
          can.width = can.width;
          ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
          ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.rect(0,0,2000,1200);
          ctx.arc(mouse.x, mouse.y, 200, 0, Math.PI*2, true)
          ctx.clip();
          ctx.fillRect(0,0,2000,1200);
    }

      var img = new Image();
      img.onload = function() {
          redraw({x: 0, y: 0})
      }

      img.src = 'http://placekitten.com/2000/1000';

      function getMouse(e, canvas) {
          var element = canvas,
          offsetX = 0,
          offsetY = 0,
          mx, my;

      // Compute the total offset. It's possible to cache this if you want
      if (element.offsetParent !== undefined) {
          do {
              offsetX += element.offsetLeft;
              offsetY += element.offsetTop;
          } while ((element = element.offsetParent));
      }

      mx = e.pageX - offsetX;
      my = e.pageY - offsetY;

      return {
          x: mx,
          y: my
      };
  }
</script>
```

[image: The Effect I want]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**USING a RADIAL gradient**

There are many ways to do that but the simplest is a gradient with an alpha.

First you need to define the size of the circle you wish to show.

```
var cirRadius = 300;
```

Then the location (canvas coordinates) where this circle will be centered

```
var posX = 100;
var posY = 100;
```

Now define the rgb colour

```
var RGB = [0,0,0] ; // black
```

Then an array of alpha values to define what is transparent

```
var alphas = [0,0,0.2,0.5,1]; // zero is transparent;
```

Now all you do is render the background image

```
// assume ctx is context and image is loaded
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height); // fill the canvas
```

Then create the gradient with it centered at the position you want and the second circle at the radius you want. The first 3 numbers define the center and radius of the start of the gradient, the last 3 define the center and radius of the end

```
var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(posX,posY,0,posX,posY,cirRadius);
```

Now add the colour stops using the CSS color string `rgba(255,255,255,1)` where the last is the alpha value from 0 to 1.

```
var len = alphas.length-1;
alphas.forEach((a,i) => {
     grad.addColorStop(i/len,`rgba(${RGB[0]},${RGB[1]},${RGB[2]},${a})`);
});
```

or for legacy browsers that do not support arrow functions or template strings

```
var i,len = alphas.length;
for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
     grad.addColorStop(i / (len - 1), "rgba(" + RGB[0] + "," + RGB[1] + "," + RGB[2] + "," + alphas[i] + ")");

}
```

Then set the fill style to the gradient

```
ctx.fillStyle = grad;
```

then just fill a rectangle covering the image

```
ctx.fillRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
```

And you are done.

By setting the position with via a mouse event and then doing the above steps 60times a second using `window.requestAnimationFrame` you can get the effect you are looking for in real time.

Here is an example

```js
// create a full screen canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); 
canvas.style.position = "absolute";
canvas.style.left     = "0px";
canvas.style.top      = "0px";
canvas.style.zIndex   = 10;
canvas.width          = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height         = window.innerHeight; 
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
// var to hold context
var ctx;


// load an image
var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7qq2.png?s=328&g=1"; 
// add resize event
var resize = function(){
    canvas.width   = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height  = window.innerHeight; 
    ctx            = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
}
// add mouse event. Because it is full screen no need to bother with offsets
var mouse = function(event){
    posX = event.clientX;
    posY = event.clientY;
}
// incase the canvas size is changed
window.addEventListener("resize",resize);

// listen to the mouse move
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",mouse)

// Call resize as that gets our context
resize();

// define the gradient
var cirRadius = 300;

var posX = 100; // this will be set by the mouse
var posY = 100;
var RGB = [0,0,0] ; // black any values from 0 to 255
var alphas = [0,0,0.2,0.5,0.9,0.95,1]; // zero is transparent one is not

// the update function
var update = function(){
    if(ctx){  // make sure all is in order..
        if(image.complete){ // draw the image when it is ready
            ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
        }else{ // while waiting for image clear the canvas
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        }
        // create gradient
        var grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(posX,posY,0,posX,posY,cirRadius);
        // add colour stops
        var len = alphas.length-1;
        alphas.forEach((a,i) => {
             grad.addColorStop(i/len,`rgba(${RGB[0]},${RGB[1]},${RGB[2]},${a})`);
        });
        // set fill style to gradient
        ctx.fillStyle = grad;
        // render that gradient
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(update); // keep doing it till cows come home.
    
}
// start it all happening;
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation! It's very helpful. Does this not work on IE? What about mobile?

Comment: @practicemakesperfect I have added details on the part that needed legacy support which is just the loop adding colour stops to the gradient. With that it will work on any browser that supports canvas